# Does MySql support specifying the group by columns to be omitted thereby using the rest of the table columns in the group by?

Tags: mysql, sql

Let say I have this table called: searches

```
------------------------------------------------
|id   |city   |keyword|app_id |page_nr|how_many|more columns here...|
|-----|-------|-------|-------|-------|--------|
|q1w2 |bern   |train  |2      |1      |10      |
|7n3m |bern   |train  |2      |2      |10      |
|l0k9 |kunming|       |4      |1      |50      |
|7b5c |kunming|       |4      |2      |50      | 
|d38j |perth  |coffee |2      |1      |5       |
|7b5c |lima   |       |2      |1      |10      |
------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to get a count of unique records without having page_nr how_many, app_id columns affect my count.

```
SELECT count(id) as total, city, keyword, more columns...
FROM searches GROUP BY total, city, keyword, more columns...
```

would get me:

```
----------------------------------------
|total|city   |keyword|other columns...|
----------------------------------------
|2    |bern   |train  | other values   |
|2    |kunming|       | other values   |
|1    |perth  |coffee | other values   |
|1    |lima   |       | other values   |
----------------------------------------
```

Does MySql have a feature which allows me to not specify explicitly which columns I would like to group by. Instead letting me specify which columns I would like to omit from the group by and have the rest of the columns in the table be specified in the group by automatically.

Something along the lines of:

```
SELECT count(id) AS total, everything_except(column_name) FROM searches GROUP BY total, everything_except(column_name)
```

Would internally be converted to

```
SELECT count(id) AS total FROM searches GROUP BY total, city, keyword, more columns here...
```

Thanks

Comment: When you do a group by you have to list the columns in the select so it's quickly done to copy and paste to the group by even if you have to add or remove over or two.

Comment: I don't think so. It would be interesting to understand more what you're trying to achieve. I don't think it's possible in the way you're suggesting, but every problem can be solved! Can you provide some examples of the expected output? I'm trying to understand why you need a dynamic GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @Kendle Thanks, yeah with full_group_by mode on I have to write out all the column names I would like included. Which is precisely what led me to think that instead of writing all those out. If they had a magic function. I could pass the ones I want omitted and have it include the rest. But it doesn't seem like it.

Comment: @MuppetDance Thanks, I am trying to get a total count of records but omit certain columns from influencing that count. However it seems that there is no way around explicitly specifying all the columns I need to be in the group by.

Comment: if there are really a load of columns you could do somthing like `select * from table_name limit 1;` and then copy & paste the column names from the top of the query results.

Comment: Why do you need a GROUP BY to do a count. Can you not perform the count using JOINS? Are you looking to use the ROLLUP feature to get counts by group? If you could write out an example of the data and how you want it to be displayed, I can put some more thought to it.

Comment: @MuppetDance I changed my example to better explain what I am asking about

Comment: If your doing `group` by for a lot of columns you must have a lot of duplicate values and should consider splitting the table into parent-child

Comment: @Kendle just trying to understand your statement here. What you are saying is if i have a search filter UI and this search filter UI has 25+ search filters which all get recorded in this table when a user runs a search. All the search filters are related to each search. You recommend splitting this table?

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I honestly can’t think of a way to do this only using SQL. The best I can come up with is to generate the SQL (including columns for GROUP BY) in code (e.g. PHP) where you can dynamically add and remove columns.

Answer (score 0):

In general, all the identifiers such as table names, column names, etc. must be explicit in an SQL query at the time you parse it in the prepare step.

The exceptions are the `*` wildcard, which expands in the select-list to the full list of columns for all tables joined in the query, or `t.*` which expands to the full list of columns for the respective table `t`.

There is no SQL syntax for `* except those I don't want`.

In other clauses, including the `GROUP BY` clause, there are no wildcards, either to include or exclude columns. You must list explicitly all the columns you want.

Older versions of SQL support ordinal numbers in place of column names in the `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses, but you would still need those columns named in the select-list to refer to them by ordinal. And IIRC this syntax is deprecated anyway.

If you want a shorter or simplified set of columns so you don't have to write them all out when you use `GROUP BY`, I suggest you consider [creating a VIEW](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html).

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't allow this (and for good reasons IMO)

What you could do, is write some SQL which generates the query for you by querying the schema tables, and excluding certain columns.

This is particularly useful if you have to do this for lots of tables, but note that it only outputs a query as a plain old text string, which you would then have to run seperately as SQL

For example..

```
// by default GROUP_CONCAT will truncate the string at 1024 characters. 
// This might not be enough for tables with lots of columns, so temporarily set it to a huge value..
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;

select 
  CONCAT('select count(id), ', GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME), ' from searches GROUP BY ', GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME)) 
from 
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns 
where 
  COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('id', 'exclude_field1', 'exclude_field2', 'etc')  and
  TABLE_SCHEMA = '<DATABASE_NAME>' and 
  TABLE_NAME = 'searches';
```

If you have lots of tables where you need to run this query AND you think the schema will change often (by adding new columns etc), then it might be a good candidiate for stored procedures.

You could adapt the above query to output a CREATE PROCEDURE statement, and then you run the output occasionally (or even automate it) to regenerate all your stored procs include the new columns.